# jedis client JAR 3.9.0 compatible with Java 11?

Tags: jedis

We are trying to upgrade jedis jar version from current 2.10.2 to 3.9.0.
But our requirement is it should be compatible with java-11 minimum.

I could not find this specific info.

Can anyone help where i can get this info for jedis v3.9.0 or later if compatible with java-11 ?

Answer (score 1):

Jedis 3.9.0 is built on Java 8. So, yes, it is compatible with Java 11.